# How to sudo -i -u user_xx without password?

Tags: sudo

I have user `automation` and want to execute a script as `app-admin` and using `app-admin` environment.
So sysadmin add these line in `etc/sudoers`:
`(automation) NOPASSWD: /path01/scripthome/startDaemon.ksh`
but when i execute `sudo -i -u automation /path01/scripthome/startDaemon.ksh`, the system asked for password.

How to sudo -i without password?

Comment: Why do you want `-i` if you just want to run a script? Doesn't running `sudo  -u automation /path01/scripthome/startDaemon.ksh` launch the script as `automation` without needing a password?

Comment: already tried without `-i` but the script has different behavior. I think the script use `app-admin` environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

sysadmin edit `/etc/sudoers` to : `(app-admin) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash -c /path01/scripthome/startDaemon.ksh` and it solve the problem.

Comment: How does running a ksh script with bash solve the problem? Oh, just noticed you're the OP. Isn't the script a ksh one?

Comment: there is shebang in the script, so when bash call the script, bash will call the ksh.